# Query to get the difference value of two different queries results

Tags: sql, oracle, plsqldeveloper

I'm trying to get the difference value of below two queries using oracle query, but I'm not getting a clue to solve it.

I have two different columns "column1" and "column2" in table "table1".

First I want the sum of column1 values and second i want the sum of column2 values - I got the queries for this

Third, I want the difference of above two results - can anyone help this out?

Query 1:

```
select sum(a.column1) as sum1
from table1 a
where a.name = 'who' and a.id = '123'
group by serialno, lastname
```

Query 2:

```
select sum(a.column2) as sum2
from table1 a
where a.name = 'who' and a.id = '123'
group by serialno, lastname
```

Comment: Why these ORDER BY clauses? Doesn't Oracle raise an error?

Comment: Does not `sum(column1) - sum(column2)` work?

Comment: its working for sum(columm1) - sum(column2). thank you

Comment: `sum(column2 - column1)` or `sum(column1 - column2)`, depending on which one you need, works equally well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Direct query:

```
select 
  sum(a.column1) as sum1, 
  sum(a.column2) as sum2, 
  sum(a.column2) - sum(a.column1) as diff  
from table1 a;
```

Example:

```
SQL> insert into table1 values (1,10);

1 row created.

SQL> insert into table1 values (2,20);

1 row created.

SQL> select sum(a.column1) as sum1, sum(a.column2) as sum2, sum(a.column2)-sum(a.column1) as diff  from table1 a;

      SUM1       SUM2       DIFF
---------- ---------- ----------
         3         30         27
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a single query to get all the 3 results you need::

```
select sum(column1),
       sum(column2),
       sum(column1) - sum(column2) as diff,
       serialno,
       lastname
from table1 a
where a.name = 'who' and a.id = '123'
group by serialno, lastname
```

Answer (score 1):

In your example, as shown by all responders, you don't need separate queries, you can do it all in one shot.

But suppose you wanted the difference between the sum of column1 for some filtering condition(s), for example `where a.id = '123'`, and other filtering condition(s), for example `where a.id = '456'`. Then you could compute the sums separately, in two independent queries, as you did. Then you use them as subqueries in a higher-level query. The subqueries should return exactly one row and one column (as your queries do), and they must be surrounded by parentheses. Like so:

```
select (select sum(column1) from table1 where id = '123) - 
                          (select sum(col1) from table1 where id = '456') from dual;
```

(Usually you don't select from dual - this expression, without "select" and "from dual", can be used wherever you would normally have a number.)

**NOTE**: This illustration is only meant to show how "scalar subqueries" can be used wherever numbers can be used. (Or, depending on the data type: scalar subqueries that return a date, or a string, can be used wherever a date or a string could be used). The example I gave, pulling sums from the same table, is inefficient and can be done better using case expressions. If the sums came from two different tables, there would be no such "more efficient" solution. See the discussion with Boneist in the comments below.

Comment: You wouldn't need two separate subqueries; you could do the same thing in a single query using a case expression, eg. `select sum(case when id = '123' then column1 end) - sum(case when id = '456' then column2 end) from table1 where id in ('123', '456');`

Comment: Well, I guessed someone would suggest that, but didn't want to make it more complicated than needed to illustrate the concept. You couldn't use case expressions if the sums were on columns in different tables. The point I was trying to make was about scalar subqueries and how they can be used.

Comment: You might want to edit your answer to make that clear then. If the columns came from different tables, that's an entirely different kettle of fish. By suggesting this to the OP (whose columns come from a single table), you're encouraging potentially worse performance (two scans through the table, rather than just one).

Answer (score 0):

Don't know why you are not using single query but anyways

you can do it like

```
select sum(a.column1) - sum(a.column2) as difference
from table1 a
where a.name = 'who' and a.id = '123'
group by serialno, lastname
```